# How to convert javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMResult() to String

Tags: java, xml, unicode, javax

I'm stuck in issue, where the XML format contains japanese character in first name and it is converted to ByteArrayInputStream and that Array is then passed to the StreamSource of javax.xml.transform.stream and we are losing the unicode characters(japanese characters) and it is replaced with ????, We are suspecting transform method and traverse method. please help us how to get back the original unicode characters or how to convert it to string. or suggest us an alternative solution.

We are using java 1.6 and tomcat 7.

i'm using the following codes,

```
String sNVPairs = "<XMLMessage><identifier>111</identifier><RegnID>10491615</RegnID><Client_Name>Binga</Client_Name><Candidate_FName>ガネーシュ</Candidate_FName><Candidate_LName>D</Candidate_LName><Candidate_ID>99296085599</Candidate_ID><Home_Zip>91505</Home_Zip><Date_Of_Request>01/20/2017</Date_Of_Request><Email_From>support@binga.com</Email_From><Email_To>Ganesh.Bhagavath@harman.com</Email_To><RA> 20 INCH TABLE TOP EXTENDER, DOUBLE TIME</RA></XMLMessage>";

String webServerStr = "http://localhost:70/email/AccomodationReuestEmail.xsl";

ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(sNVPairs.getBytes());

javax.xml.transform.Source xmlSource = new javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource(in);

javax.xml.transform.Source xsltSource =new javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource(webServerStr);

javax.xml.transform.Result result = new javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMResult();

javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory transFact =
              javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory.newInstance( );

javax.xml.transform.Transformer trans;

try {
        trans = transFact.newTransformer(xsltSource);
        trans.transform(xmlSource, result);

        EMailParser msgFinder = new EMailParser();
        TreeWalker tw = new TreeWalker(msgFinder);
        tw.traverse(((DOMResult)result).getNode());
}
catch (TransformerConfigurationException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    } catch (TransformerException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```

This is the EMailParser code,

```
public class EMailParser extends org.xml.sax.HandlerBase{
//boolean variables which stores the flag corresponding the element
private boolean m_bFrom = false;
private boolean m_bTo   = false;
private boolean m_bCc   = false;
private boolean m_bBCc   = false;
private boolean m_bBody = false;
private boolean m_bSub  = false;

//string variables to store the contents of each tag
private String m_sMsgFrom = "";
private String m_sMsgTo   = "";
private String m_sMsgCc   = "";
private String m_sMsgBCc  = "";
private String m_sMsgSub  = "";
private String m_sMsgBody = "";

/**
 * Constructor which calls the Baseclass Constructor
 */
public EMailParser()
{
    super();
}

/**
 * Print any text found inside an element.
 * @param chars  character array to be processed
 * @param iStart  the index from where the array has to be read
 * @param iLen  the length to which the array has to be read
 */

public void characters(char[] chars, int iStart, int iLen)
{
    String sValue = new String(chars, iStart, iLen);
    if(m_bFrom)
        m_sMsgFrom += sValue;
    else if(m_bTo)
        m_sMsgTo += sValue;
    else if(m_bCc)
        m_sMsgCc += sValue;
    else if(m_bBCc)
        m_sMsgBCc += sValue;
    else if(m_bSub)
        m_sMsgSub += sValue;
    else if(m_bBody)
        m_sMsgBody += sValue;
}

/**
 * function which returns the whole message
 * @return emessage the full message
 */

public EMessage getMessage()
{
    return new EMessage(m_sMsgFrom,m_sMsgTo,m_sMsgCc,m_sMsgBCc,m_sMsgSub,m_sMsgBody);
}
/**
 * Mark the element end and make the corresponding flag false.
 * @param element  the tag name
 */

public void endElement(String element)
{
    if (element.equals("xmlMessageFrom"))
    {
        m_bFrom = false;
    }
    else if(element.equals("xmlMessageTo"))
    {
        m_bTo = false;
    }
    else if(element.equals("xmlMessageCc"))
    {
        m_bCc = false;
    }
    else if(element.equals("xmlMessageBCc"))
    {
        m_bBCc = false;
    }
    else if(element.equals("xmlMessageBody"))
    {
        m_bBody = false;
    }
    else if(element.equals("xmlMessageSubject"))
    {
        m_bSub = false;
    }
}

/**
 * Mark the element start and make the corresponding flag true
 * @param element  the tag name
 * @param attrlist  attributes of the tag
 */

public void startElement(String element, org.xml.sax.AttributeList attrlist)
{
    if (element.equals("xmlMessageFrom"))
    {
        m_bFrom = true;
    }
    else if(element.equals("xmlMessageTo"))
    {
        m_bTo = true;
    }
    else if(element.equals("xmlMessageCc"))
    {
        m_bCc = true;
    }
    else if(element.equals("xmlMessageBCc"))
    {
        m_bBCc = true;
    }
    else if(element.equals("xmlMessageBody"))
    {
        m_bBody = true;
    }
    else if(element.equals("xmlMessageSubject"))
    {
        m_bSub = true;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Whoever posted the solution earlier, sorry it's working.. it was typing mistake.

Comment: ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(sNVPairs.getBytes("UTF8"));
This is the solution.. Thanks mate, it helped a lot :)